# Processing mousePressed() issue

Tags: processing

Ok so basically when user presses on a box the value is suppose to only reduce once but it continuously does that. Here's a snippet of my code:

```java
int balance = 100;
void mousePressed {
     if (mouseX > posX && mouseX < posX + w && mouseY > posY && mouseY < posY 
     + h) {
          balance -= 5;
     }
}
```

So if they click on the box balance will continuously drop by 5, when I only want it to happen once. How do I stop this?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question (which is a bit difficult, since you didn't post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), I believe you're asking how to only allow a user to click once instead of detecting every click.

If that's the case, then the answer is to use a `boolean` variable that simply keeps track of whether the user has already clicked the mouse. Here's my own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```java
boolean alreadyPressed = false;

void mousePressed() {
  if (!alreadyPressed) {
    println("pressed");
    alreadyPressed = true;
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
}
```